# How export all records from gird using xlsx. Now I can see the only top 100 row in xlsx file

Tags: javascript, xlsx, sheetjs, js-xlsx

I have implemented like This.
The grid has multiple pages, and after exporting the file in xlsx format, the file contained only the first page data. so how can I download all rows? can you please help me here?

```
const InvestigationTable1 = document.getElementById("invtbl");

function ExportTOExcel(InvestigationTable ? : any) {
  var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(InvestigationTable, < XLSX.Table2SheetOpts > {
    sheet: "Sheet JS"
  });
  var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {
    bookType: 'xlsx',
    bookSST: true,
    type: 'binary'
  });

  const blob = new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], {
    type: "application/octet-stream"
  });

  download(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], {
    type: "application/octet-stream"
  }), 'test.xlsx');
}
```